# TexMaths BASIC doesn't open in Libre Office - BASIC runtime error

Tags: libreoffice, latex

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
LibreOffice 6.3.1.2
TexMaths 0.48

When I click on the TexMaths icon in LibreOffice Writer, I get the error:

[image]

Interestingly, if I write some Latex, I can select it and click on the TexMaths icon and it does turn my Latex into an image of the equation, but it's not editable.

More of the error message whenever I click on the icon (if I haven't selected Latex in the document first):

[image]